# knockout updating the property of observable array's each element using data from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a ViewModel "`AppViewModel`" which is getting a `JSON` data to create the model from, one of the property "`totalSessions`" is to be fetched using an `ajax` call, the "model" `AppViewModel` returns an observable array, My code is running without any errors but the view doesn't seem to update.

```
    var jsonapparray = [];

   function AppViewModel(appsdata)
{
    var self = this;        
    var appsdata = $.parseJSON("["+ JSON.stringify(appsdata["user_of"]) + "]");

    var totalSessions = 0;
    var i = 0;               
    for (var appkey in appsdata[0]) {
      console.log(appsdata[0][appkey].name);
      var elem = new Object();
      elem._id = appsdata[0][appkey]._id;
      elem.category = appsdata[0][appkey].category;
      elem.country = appsdata[0][appkey].country;
      elem.name = appsdata[0][appkey].name;
      elem.key = appsdata[0][appkey].key;
      elem.timezone = appsdata[0][appkey].timezone;
      elem.totalsessions = 000;   
      jsonapparray.push(elem);
      updateSessionsInfo(i,elem,jsonapparray);
      i++;    
    }

    self.AppCount = i;
    self.Apps = ko.observableArray(jsonapparray);   

    function updateSessionsInfo(i,elem,jsonapparray)
    {          
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:Domain + "/o",
                data:{
                    "api_key":readCookie("api_key"),
                    "app_id":elem._id,
                    "method":"sessions"
                },
                dataType:"jsonp",
                async: false,
                success:function (json) {                   
                    _sessionDb = json;
                    var totalSessions = _.pluck(_sessionDb,"t");                                    
                    jsonapparray[j].totalsessions = totalSessions[0];
                }
            });     
    }   

}
```

Comment: Where does the `j` in `jsonapparray[j].totalsessions` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
jsonapparray[j].totalsessions = totalSessions[0];
```

to:

```
jsonapparray[i].totalsessions = totalSessions[0];
```

But that won't actually help. Updating a property of an item in the array won't trigger an update. You should make all your properties observable, for example:

```
elem.totalsessions = ko.observable(0);
```

and then update the value like this:

```
jsonapparray[i].totalsessions(totalsessions[0]);
```